# Use "Business Hours" on a custom process?

Tags: apex, bestpractice

I have the following  requirement:

> From 8AM to 5PM i should add **X** value to some **lead's custom
> field** this should happen to new leads being inserted, any insertion
> outside of that range should not be affected by this custom process...

Is it a good idea to take advantage of the tools (BusinessHours class) and configurations provided by "Business hours"???

I was thinking on creating a new "Organization Business Hours" configuration... I would set the range of business hours from 8PM to 5PM and then from apex i would use the BusinessHours class' methods to check if the current insertion is happening withing business hrs.

Any advises / suggestions, will i mess with other processes (like Entitlement processe or case escalations) by doing this?

Comment: Personally, every time I try to use a Salefsorce feature for something slightly different, it comes back to bite me. Having said that, your requirement is very high level and there are a lot of factors that could play into this.  It seems simple enough to just do this in a flow.  Why complicate it with business hours?

Comment: Business Hours - you can configure multiple sets of them and integrate holidays. Entitlement processes and escalation rules use whatever business hours are configured to the process/Case so creating a new Bus Hours config should not affect them unless you have some logic elsewhere that assumes only 1 business hours config exists.  I'd go for it as you're externalizing business hours and won't have to touch flow/apex thereafter